# PHP require thousands of files performance issue

Tags: php, autoload

I would like to ask about php performance when you are about to require hundreds or thousand of files dynamically.

See script below

**[Folders]**

*product*  (50 files)

*user* (20 files)

*report* (91 files)

each folder has a lot files but these files as classes. Example below

```
class cls_product_01 {
   public $db;
   function __construct($dbconn){
      $this->db = $dbconn;
   }

   function saveProduct(){
     //PS: the saveproduct.ext.php is a normal code (native approach)
     require __dir__ .'/product/saveproduct.ext.php';
   }

}
```

I have simple controller that will dynamically call the class based on the ajax params

```
$newAjaxClass = 'cls_'. $_POST['actionid'];
$newApp = new $newAjaxClass($dbconn);
```

I would like to require all the ajax file on each folder by looping.
Does this slow down the website since there are a lot of files?

PS: I am rewriting this code due to difficulty in maintaining code from the previous developer.

QUESTIONS: With that approach in mind will the application slows down if I load/required all files from the start this is similar to autoloading but I a bit hesitant if including a lot of files will slow down (eat a lot of ram) in the process. Especially I'll be including maybe about 300 to 400 files combined all folders.

I understand that using _autoload with make this easier since it will load the dependency dynamically. The big question is will using autoload with these a lot of script slows down the app? With that hundred of files how much RAM will the autoload eat?

Comment: whats in all theses files?

Comment: this application is a pos/inventory app (local). The old developer is just requiring this files took me long time to follow his code.

Comment: that doesnt answer my question

Comment: I don't get it. These file contains separate saving and update functions to the database and some codes are writing a textfile for export. The old developer uses different approach he is using include_once approach and I found a lot of redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `spl_autoload_register()`.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.class.php';
});
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

This is lazy loading and hence it won't include all your files upfront unless they are required.

For an example, if you were to load `cls_product_01`, calling:

```
new `cls_product_01();`
```

will look for the file `cls_product_01.class.php` and it will be included. However your case seems very cumbersome and I think you seriously need to consider your design again. And also I don't think it's a good idea to include files based on user provided data. [ like `$newAjaxClass = 'cls_'. $_POST['actionid'];`]

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi thank you for the comment, yeah that $newAjaxClass is for example only. My concern is the memory  since I don't want my login script to consume 4mb or ram. Since you said it is lazy loading I'll try this approach. I hope this won't affect the server badly. thank you.

Comment: Yes, if you aren't calling / instantiating all the classes at once, it won't include all of them, thus it will not consume much memory. But it's not really a good idea to use the autoloader with user provided values!

Comment: why? I will be having a list of allowable values. The logic is check if the ajax action exist in the list then instantiate that class otherwise kill the script and display error 'route denied, not found'. That list (array) is a long single dimension array. Do you have a better approach to do this?

Comment: It's not a problem since you validate the provided class name against a set of valid values. I just stated a common practice of not using user provided data straight away. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out autoloading.
http://php.net/__autoload

Basically if you tell it how it'll know where to find the file, given the class name, then you don't need to require them all up front.

Comment: hi I already read this and I'm still hesitant if using this approach slows down the application since there are 300-400 files needs to be required at the startup. different classes (OOP approach)

Comment: does using autoload with this big files eats a lot of ram?

Comment: Thank you. I've searched about this lazy loading.. thank you.